# cp --reflink=auto for MacOS X

Tags: file-copy, hfs+, deduplication

`cp --reflink=auto` shows following output for MacOS:

> cp: illegal option -- -

Is copy-on-write or deduplication supported for HFS? How can I COW huge files with HFS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple's new APFS filesystem supports copy-on-write; CoW is automatically enabled in Finder copy operations where available, and when using `cp -c` on the command line.

Unfortunately, `cp -c` is equivalent to `cp --reflink=always` (not `auto`), and will fail when copy-on-write is not possible with

```
cp: somefile: clonefile failed: Operation not supported
```

I'm not aware of a way to get `auto` behavior. You could make a shell script or function with automatic fallback *a la*

```
cpclone() { cp -c "$@" || cp "$@"; }
```

but it'll be difficult to make it entirely reliable for all edge cases.

Comment: Seems to work for me. How do you check the copy is actually a reflink?

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel The easiest, cross-platform way is to time it: just copy a 512M file. Reflink happens at the extent level, so there should be no expectation for knowing it from, say, reading the inode. I am not aware of any command-line interface to the physical extent on APFS.

Answer (score 5):

Updated November 2021: This answer has been rendered obsolete by oncoming coreutils changes. reflink=auto has been the default since [25725f9](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/25725f9d41735d176d73a757430739fb71c7d043) (coreutils 9.0). APFS cloning is committed in the tree as [5e36c0c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/5e36c0ce078a65c7dac6ac5ebdfb0cf096856427) and should appear in coreutils 9.1.

---

Original posting November 2019: I wrote [a patch](https://github.com/Artoria2e5/coreutils/commit/22fccf16496a308d599baaec516b68f85b82f018) ([mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2019-11/msg00001.html)) for GNU coreutils that enables `--reflink` for macOS > 10.12. Yes, `--reflink=auto` will work, at least according to my time measurements.

Here are two ways to use it:

- clone the git repository, run `./bootstrap`, and then the usual `./configure -C` and `make -j12 install`.
- Apply the patch ([rebased for 8.31](https://github.com/Artoria2e5/coreutils/commit/bcbc36a9a4110626e10c5bd2a248c4d9dafb8829.patch)) to another version of coreutils to skip the painful bootstrapping.

You can grab a bunch of possible parameters to use from [the homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/coreutils.rb). Since the change is only useful for `cp` and `mv` only, you can opt to only replace these two binaries. (`mv` with reflink is useful for submodules.)

---

There is an [associated patch](https://github.com/Artoria2e5/coreutils/commit/d38bf6efbd3cb44fd2c13d5342ba28924e8959c4.patch) that enables reflink=auto by default for `cp` and `install` too. If you keep forgetting about adding the option or want faster `ginstall` in your Makefiles, try it.

Comment: fwiw regarding the update: I have `cp` from coreutils v9.4 on Mac and it fails when using `--reflink=always`. Only `/bin/cp -c` works.

Comment: @hraban hmm, `gcp --reflink=always` is working on my end. It's also 9.4... macOS 13.6.4, bottled binary from homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

[uutils](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils) is a GNU coreutils clone written in Rust and [supports reflink copies on macOS' APFS](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/issues/1773) via the same syntax as GNU coreutils does on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `--reflink=auto` option wasn't available in MacOS just yet. HFS also does not natively support CoW (Copy on Write).

Perhaps in future such support will be added - likely when ZFS becomes natively available or another native filesystem adds support.

I suggest referring to the man page to get the options that are currently available to you: `man cp`

---

NOTE:

In MacOS, most commands (including `cp`) only support short options, not long options. Thus, if there were an equivalent, it would be a single character only. Example would be `-L` or `--dereference` available in GNU coreutils' version of `cp`. In MacOS, only `-L` is available.